# Vlookup with If Statement

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I would like to use Vlookup function with If statement. My issue is if any rows in K columns equal to "Hatalı" then vlookup has to be begin according to the below parameters.

For below code it gaves me compile error says "Next witout For" but I can not handle it. I will be glad if anyone can help me to resolve.

```
Sub FINDSource()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Dept_Row As Long
    Dim Dept_Clm As Long

    Table1 = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("B9:B10000")
    Table2 = Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:C5000")
    Dept_Row = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("M9").Row
    Dept_Clm = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("M9").Column



        For Each cl In Table1


        If Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("K:K").Value = "Hatalı" Then
        Worksheets("RegScenario").Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
        Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
        Next cl
        MsgBox "Done"

    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Your `End If` is outside the `For Each` loop.

Comment: @Jacob is right. Indent your code and you will see

Comment: `dim table1 as range` then `SET Table1 = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("B9:B10000")` Same for table2.

Comment: @Jacob, sorry but where should I put that ? Should use next also ?

Comment: @Jeeped, this is not my issue but thanks for your advice I settle that.

Comment: Don't ever use `On Error Resume Next` without a proper error handling. This just mutes your errors but they still occur. It just makes you blind for errors but they are still there. You just cannot debug a code properly if there is `On Error Resume Next` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**: if you indent your code properly, you would find your `If` is missing an `End If`.

**Second**: avoid using `On Error Resume Next`, instead handle your errors. In your case, you need to make sure `VLookup` is able to find `cl` in `Table2` range, otherwise it will result with an error. You can use `If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(cl.Value, Table2, 2, 0)) Then` to trap this error.

**Third**: you need to `Set` your `Table1` and `Table2` `Range` objects.

More explanation inside the code below:

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub FINDSource()

Dim Table1 As Range, Table2 As Range, cl As Range
Dim Dept_Row As Long
Dim Dept_Clm As Long

' Set the Range Object
Set Table1 = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("B9:B10000")

' Set the Range Object
Set Table2 = Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:C5000")

Dept_Row = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("M9").Row '<-- this equals to 9, Anyway you have "M9" hard-coded
Dept_Clm = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("M9").Column '<-- this equals to 13, Anyway you have "M9" hard-coded

With Worksheets("RegScenario")
    For Each cl In Table1
        If .Range("K" & cl.Row).Value2 = "Hatali" Then ' check if column K at the same row of Table1 Range = "Hatali"

            ' need to trap the error in case Vlookup unable to find a match in Table2 Range
            If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(cl.Value, Table2, 2, 0)) Then
                .Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.VLookup(cl.Value, Table2, 2, 0)
            End If

            Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
        End If

    Next cl
End With

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This should fix the error "Next without For"

```
    Sub FINDSource()

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim Dept_Row As Long
    Dim Dept_Clm As Long

    Table1 = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("B9:B10000")
    Table2 = Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:C5000")
    Dept_Row = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("M9").Row
    Dept_Clm = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("M9").Column

        For Each cl In Table1
          If cl.Value = "Hatalı" Then
          Worksheets("RegScenario").Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
          Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
          End If        
        Next cl
        MsgBox "Done"

    End Sub
```

Comment: `If Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("K:K").Value = "Hatalı" Then` will result with an error, did you test this code before posting ?

Comment: I just corrected the structure to fix the 'Next without For' issue. Just edited the code for the follow-up issue. @GamzeUral please check this one now.

Comment: Since it not specified what exactly is intended, I assumed you want to check the `cl` value. Else you need to replace `Range("K:K")` by `Range("K" & i)` where `i` is a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little unclear on what you are trying to do with `Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("K:K")`.

```
option explicit

sub FINDSource()
    Dim Dept_Row As Long, Dept_Clm As Long
    dim Table1 as range, table2 as range, cl as range

    set Table1 = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("B9:B10000")
    set Table2 = Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:C5000")
    'Dept_Row = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("M9").Row
    Dept_Clm = Worksheets("RegScenario").Range("M9").Column

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each cl In Table1
        If cl.offset(0, 9).Value = "Hatalı" Then
            Worksheets("RegScenario").Cells(cl.row, Dept_Clm) = _
                Application.VLookup(cl.value, Table2, 2, False)
            Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1
        else if
            'code for non-Hatalı
        End If
    Next cl

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: that works for me thanks.. So if I want to use else if do no nothing how can I do that?

Comment: Appreciate but I aware another issue right now. Lets say K9 AND K12 is equal to "Hatalı". But according to this formula the result is appear in M9 and M10. but the vloouk up result has to be M9 and M12. I have no idea how can I handle this??

Comment: The `cl.row` should take care of that. The `Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1` is unnecessary.